# stringstream::operator>> only read, and not extract next token from stream

Tags: c++, stringstream

How can I just read the first new "token" (standard non-whitespace character sequence, as beautifully extracted by operator>>) without removing it from the stream? Can I extract the string, check if it needs to be put back, and reset the internal stream iterator? I think this might work, but have no idea how to implement it...

Example:

```
#include <string>
    using std::string;
#include <sstream>
    using std::stringstream;

int main()
{
    string s("test string \\ bla blie");
    stringstream ss(s);

    string token;
    while( ss >> token )
    {
        if( "\\" == token )
            break;
        else
            cout << "Token is: " << token << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would a `tellg` and `seekg` work here before and conditionally after the stream extraction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would a tellg and seekg work here before and conditionally after the stream extraction?

Yes.

Comment: All, right, implemented and it works. Dang, C++ is powerful :D. Thanks for  the push of confidence. If anyone wants the implementation, please ask for a simplified example (my code is quite class-centric, meaning all variables are pretty delocalised so I can't copy-paste the code.